# Do JWT tokens always need to be sent via the Authorization header

Tags: jwt

We have a web service that maintains no state (not even a session state), so we transfer JWT tokens between the server and the client which contains the encrypted state of the client.

However, we also want to protect the web service endpoints using the standard authorization features of the server, like basic auth.

All documentation I have seen around JWT tokens indicates that they should be sent via the Authorization header, which makes it incompatible with something like basic auth. I know there is nothing to stop us from sending the token via another header, but is there some best practice around mixing standard authorization techniques that use the Authorization header and JWT tokens? Failing that, is there any guidelines or practices that state you should not sent JWT tokens in headers other than Authorization?

Comment: Is it machine to machine or is the client untrusted (ie JavaScipt enabled web browser)?

Comment: The client is an untrusted browser.

Comment: If the JWT isn't used for authorization you probably shouldn't send it in the authorization header. Cookies were invented for keeping track of state, so just send the JWT in a cookie and use the authorization header for the BA.

Comment: I would say that the common practice is that Basic Auth (or any other authentication) is done once in exchange for a JWT, then future authentications (and authorizations) are accomplished by the JWT. That's why it's normally sent via the Authentication header.

If you for some reason would like to stick with Basic Auth for authentication for every call to the backend, the JWT is no longer used for authentication and you have to put it in an X-header. Question is, if you have the state (including "logged in:true/false) in JWT, why would you want to repeat the Authentication process reach call?